# Magento 2: When updating order status programmatically, order is always set to closed

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In my Magento 2 store, I have an observer that, given some conditions, should update the order status as "complete".

```
<?php

namespace MyNameSpace\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class SalesOrderShipmentTrackSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(

    ) {
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        ...

        $order->setState(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $order->setStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $order->addStatusToHistory(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
        $order->save();

        ...
    }
}
```

The observer is called when expected, and the `$order->save()` is being called on the correct order(I've checked using the debugger), but after the code has executed, the order is saved as `closed` and not as `completed`.

Looking at `magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php` I can see that `const STATE_COMPLETE = 'complete';`

Could there be any reason for this behaviour? My Magento version is 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, and found the solution right here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283449/111506

I hope that it helps you !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).